# Checking subspaces for independence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, algebraic-independence

Assume: $V:= \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] = \left \{ a+b \sqrt{2} \right \}$
My task is to check if the following subset is linear independent:  $\\$

$\left \{ 10, 3+ \sqrt{2} \right \}$

My approach: $\alpha 10 + \beta ({3+ \sqrt{2}})=0$.
I am looking for a non trivial solution. Therefore I am searching for  at least one facor $\alpha$ , $\beta$ such that one term cancels out and I can set the other factor to zero therefore the hole equation is zero. But I have no idea how to solve it..

Comment: As a stylistic matter, you should specify that we're talking about linear independence over $\Bbb Q$.  Your set would not be linearly independent over $\Bbb R$, or even over $F= \Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]$.  You know that the set $\{1, \sqrt 2 \}$ is linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$, right?  Rearrange the terms of $10 \alpha + (3 + \sqrt 2) \beta$ to exploit that knowledge.

Comment: Yes I know that the set ist linearly independent. But how can this help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Try to express that square root. Remember that all elementary operations are closed in the set of rational numbers.

**Solution:**

> So we have $$\beta \sqrt{2} = -10\alpha -3\beta$$ Now if $\beta \ne 0$ then $$ \sqrt{2} = {-10\alpha -3\beta\over \beta}$$ which i nonsense since LHS is irational and RHS is not. So $\beta =0$...

Comment: Ok understood. But then has  $\alpha$ not to be zero otherwise there exists no factor such that the equation equals zero and therefore it's linearly independent?

Comment: Then you get $10\alpha =0$ ...

Comment: Alternatively, $(10 \alpha + 3 \beta) \cdot 1 + \beta \sqrt 2 =0$, and since $\{1, \sqrt 2 \}$ is linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$, we have $10 \alpha + 3 \beta = \beta = 0 \Rightarrow \beta = \alpha = 0$.